# Calling shortcode function from wordpress page editor

Tags: php, wordpress

Having an issue calling shortcode from a wordpress page editor, even though I can call the shortcode from a php theme file with no problem

I have this in my functions.php file:

```
function new_loop() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'discounts',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_query($args);
    $string = "<div class='container'>";
    $string .= "<div class='row'>";
    if($my_query->have_posts()):
        while($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            $custom = get_post_custom( get_the_ID() );
            $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID(), 'full');

            $string .= "<div class='col-md-4 my-2'>" . " <div class='discount-container shadow' style='background: url(". $thumbnail . "); background-size:cover; background-position:center;'>  ". "<div class='discount-content'>" . "<p class='discount-title font-weight-bold'>" .get_the_title(). "</p>" . "<div class='discount-desc' id='discount-description'>" . get_the_content() ."</div>" . "<a class='discount-link' href=". get_the_permalink() .">" . "Open in new tab" . "</a>" ."</div>" ."</div>" . "</div>" ;
        endwhile;

    $string .= "</div>";
      $string .= "</div>";
      return $string;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
    endif;
}
add_shortcode( 'calling_loop', 'new_loop' );
```

if I do  then it works fine. But in a wordpress editor page where I just have [calling_loop] it doesn't work and I get a notice that my callback is wrong because it can't find variable $post

How would I properly make this work by just calling the shortcode snippet in the page editor?

Comment: At the top of your function, try putting `$post = get_post();`

Comment: That didn't get it for me, unfortunately, but I was able to use get_the_ID() and figure it out from there. Thanks@

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have used the $post and $post is not define.

so, there are two option for this solution.

1. you can use the `$my_query->ID` rather than `$post->ID`
2. you can user the `get_the_ID()` rather than `$post->ID`

As per my suggestion I would like to **suggest first option**.

Also Here I have shared the some tips of WordPress which you need to care in your function.

=> As per the WordPress standard if you want to use the shortcode in the editor than please use the `the_content()` function rather than the `get_the_content()`.